# How to get delta from eventResize event of Fullcalendar for a start date

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using Fullcalendar event `eventResize`. What I'm trying to achieve, is to get a start date delta after resizing a left part of an event. I can get the end date delta, whet I resize a right part of an event, but I can't find how to get the start date delta. My code is:

```
eventResize: function (event, delta) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(delta);

  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/path-to-controller',
    data: {
      id: event['id'],
      days_to_date: delta ? delta['_days'] : ''
    }
  })
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be a bug. Normally moving the start time counts as a "drop" event rather than "resize", but in a Scheduler timeline view, as you noticed, you can move the event around by grabbing the left edge. It has the same effect (it changes the start _and_ end times, thus _moving_ the event instead of _resizing_ it), but it gets triggered as a "resize" event nonetheless. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/toytd26b/4/ using Scheduler 1.9. IMO Either you should be allowed to actually resize by dragging the start time, and a delta be provided, or it should trigger the "drop" event instead.

Comment: Bugs can be reported by following the guidance here: https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Reporting-Bugs/